# Why does my iPhone 5c say it cannot take new photos even after I delete 100 or so?

Tags: photos, iphone

I tried to take a photo but got an error message saying storage was full.

So, I deleted about 100 photos (from both Camera Roll and Recently Deleted), but I still get the same message.

On top of that I also deleted about 40 mp3s and 3 or 4 apps and restarted the phone, but it's still the same.

Whats the deal?

Comment: What does your iphone say is taking up the most space? 
Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage

Does anything in there look odd?

Comment: @DanHergenreder 'Other' is taking up the most space

Comment: Do a full backup/restore with iTunes and should clear up the problem. Happened to my girlfriend.

Answer (score 1):

### Restore from a backup.

It looks like there are a lot of cached files on your phone that shouldn't be there. Usually restoring from a backup will clear all of this system trash as it only backs up personal information.

**Note:** an iTunes backup will be more complete and will contain a lot more app data than iCloud, so that is recommended if you are able to use iTunes.

#### iTunes (recommended)

1. Make an iTunes backup. Connect your phone to your computer, and open iTunes. Select **Your iPhone** (in the top bar) **- Summary - Back Up Now.**
2. Disable Find My iPhone. Go to **Settings - Apple ID - iCloud - Find My iPhone** and turn off the switch. You will have to enter your Apple ID password.

   - If you have forgotten your Apple ID password, go to **[iForgot](http://iforgot.apple.com)**
3. In iTunes, click **Restore iPhone**.
4. Wait for the restore to complete
5. In Setup Assistant, select that you'd like to restore from an iTunes backup and follow the directions from there.

---

#### iCloud

1. Make an iCloud Backup. Go to **Settings - Apple ID** (big thing with your name at the top) **- iCloud - iCloud Backup - Back Up Now**
2. Disable Find My iPhone. Go to **Settings - Apple ID - iCloud - Find My iPhone** and turn off the switch. You will have to enter your Apple ID password.

   - If you have forgotten your Apple ID password, go to **[iForgot](http://iforgot.apple.com)**
3. Wipe your phone. Go to **Settings - General - Reset - Erase All Content and Settings**.
4. Wait for your phone to do a full wipe.
5. In Setup Assistant, select that you'd like to restore from an iCloud backup. Choose your desired iCloud backup.

That's it! See if it worked.